# Samba server permissions not work

Tags: permissions, samba, ubuntu-14.04

I have Samba server installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I set up some smb shares for everyone.

For example this is a part of my smb.conf:

```
[logs]
        path = /srv01/logs
        browsable = yes
        read only = no
    force create mask = 0777
    force direcory mode = 0777
```

This shared folder can open everyone user (it works without auth) and everyone have read/write permissions.

And now my problem. 
When some user create new folder in this share (\myserver\logs) created folder have 0755 permissions for user nobody.
But in my smb.conf i set 0777 permission via this strings:

```
force create mask = 0777
force direcory mode = 0777
```

What I do wrong? 
I need 0777 permissions for every new file or folder in my share

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

instead. Don't forget to reload the configuration.

Comment: My mistake. I change string in config and now it works! Thank you!